# Personalized table with 1 row and 2 columns

Tags: html, css

I want to make a table with space between columns, on a background, like this :

[image]

And when I resize my page the text should not exit from box

```css
#banner {
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 70px;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 455px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-right: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.r1c1 {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
}
.r2c1 {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <div class="r1c1">

    <h2>Once you've experienced the pleasure and comfort of hydronic heating, there's no going back.</h2> 
  </div>
  <div class="r2c1">
    <img class="voucher1" src="voucher1.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you really have to use table?

Comment: OP is probably referring to *layout*, not *table*.

Comment: @3rdthemagical no, i want something to look like that

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to use a table, I would suggest using the `<table>` element directly. If instead you're making something like the display in your attached image, I have a few suggestions:

1. try using margins to keep the table cells separated
2. try placing a container div around your text and controlling its size to create the appearance that the cells have spaces between them.
3. try using Twitter Bootstrap. It's open source and fantastic and very easy to use. It has presets for a ton of different elements. Making what you want would be as simple as:

   ```
   <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5" id="r1c1"><div>
   <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2" id="spacer"><div>
   <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5" id="r2c1"><div>
   ```

Without having to further define the col-lg and col-md classes, you've taken advantage of bootstraps grid system and created a scalable table. Hope that helps!